# Fetch IP Address with Ipify

Tags: geolocation, fetch-api

I'm doing a Frontend Mentor challenge. My goal is basically just to fetch my own IP address when I submit a form. I'm using the IP Geolocation API by IPify for the first time. So I wrote a function(fetchIP) which works quit good and logs my IP to the console when I call it. But if try to call it in another function the console just stays empty.

```
    const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitIP");


    const apiKey = '';
    const url = `https://api.ipify.org/?format=json&apiKey=${apiKey}`;

    async function fetchIP() {
      alert("function fetchIP was called")
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json);
    }


    function showIP() {
      const inputIP = document.getElementById("ipAddress").value;
       if(inputIP !== "") {
        fetchIP();
       } else {
         alert("Please enter a valid IP address")
       }
     }

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", showIP);
```

I already tried to add another event listener on my submitButton but the console still stays empty.  I also put an alert message in the fetch function which will be displayed when I call it in another function but there's simply no data logged to the console.

Comment: Is API support CORS?